# Why is my stylesheet being ignored by a stylesheet with a lower specificity?

Tags: css, breakpoints, css-specificity

I created a spacing-element that uses two classes:

`.spacer-mobile-M = spacing height on mobile devices`

`.spacer-desktop-0 = spacing height on desktop devices (only active @media (min-width: 992px))`

```css
.spacer-blank {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.spacer-mobile-M {
    height: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .spacer-desktop-0 {
        height: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer-blank spacer-mobile-M spacer-desktop-0" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

The expected behavior on a 1200px wide screen would be, that the mobile-spacer is being overwritten by the desktop style (higher specificity due to media query and defined later in the code).

However, right now, the desktop spacer is being overwritten by the mobile style.

I only experience this behavior with a spacer that has a lower height than the mobile value.

Is there a rule, that classes with `height: 0` or lower height than the general one (without media query) can be overwritten? I can't find anything in Google when I search for specificity.

Thanks for a short hint.

Comment: Is there no other element that you could add padding or a margin to?

Comment: Hi @Peter - I've converted the code you posted to a snippet and as you can see it actually appears to do exactly what you described you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be use two different CSS classes for the same element. If you use media queries, why don't use the same class? For example:

```
.spacer {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .spacer {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

`<div class="spacer" aria-hidden="true"></div>`

I don't know the rest of the code, but if on desktop size you want simply hide the spacer also you can use:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .spacer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```